# Getting specific value from XML HTTP Client Response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, simplexml

I am communicating with a domain registrar API, where I make a call to get available TLD list.

The response should look like this in a browser:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApiResponse xmlns="http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response" Status="OK">
  <Errors />
  <RequestedCommand>namecheap.domains.getTldList</RequestedCommand>
  <CommandResponse Type="namecheap.domains.getTldList">
    <Tlds>
      <Tld Name="biz" NonRealTime="false" MinRegisterYears="1" MaxRegisterYears="10" MinRenewYears="1" MaxRenewYears="10" MinTransferYears="1" MaxTransferYears="10" IsApiRegisterable="true" IsApiRenewable="true" IsApiTransferable="false" IsEppRequired="false" IsDisableModContact="false" IsDisableWGAllot="false" IsIncludeInExtendedSearchOnly="false" SequenceNumber="5" Type="GTLD" IsSupportsIDN="false" Category="P">US Business</Tld>
      <Tld Name="bz" NonRealTime="false" MinRegisterYears="1" MaxRegisterYears="10" MinRenewYears="1" MaxRenewYears="10" MinTransferYears="1" MaxTransferYears="10" IsApiRegisterable="false" IsApiRenewable="false" IsApiTransferable="false" IsEppRequired="false" IsDisableModContact="false" IsDisableWGAllot="false" IsIncludeInExtendedSearchOnly="true" SequenceNumber="11" Type="CCTLD" IsSupportsIDN="false" Category="A">BZ Country Domain</Tld>
      <Tld Name="ca" NonRealTime="true" MinRegisterYears="1" MaxRegisterYears="10" MinRenewYears="1" MaxRenewYears="10" MinTransferYears="1" MaxTransferYears="10" IsApiRegisterable="false" IsApiRenewable="false" IsApiTransferable="false" IsEppRequired="false" IsDisableModContact="false" IsDisableWGAllot="false" IsIncludeInExtendedSearchOnly="true" SequenceNumber="7" Type="CCTLD" IsSupportsIDN="false" Category="A">Canada Country TLD</Tld>
      <Tld Name="cc" NonRealTime="false" MinRegisterYears="1" MaxRegisterYears="10" MinRenewYears="1" MaxRenewYears="10" MinTransferYears="1" MaxTransferYears="10" IsApiRegisterable="false" IsApiRenewable="false" IsApiTransferable="false" IsEppRequired="false" IsDisableModContact="false" IsDisableWGAllot="false" IsIncludeInExtendedSearchOnly="true" SequenceNumber="9" Type="CCTLD" IsSupportsIDN="false" Category="A">CC TLD</Tld>
      <Tld Name="co.uk" NonRealTime="false" MinRegisterYears="2" MaxRegisterYears="10" MinRenewYears="2" MaxRenewYears="10" MinTransferYears="2" MaxTransferYears="10" IsApiRegisterable="true" IsApiRenewable="false" IsApiTransferable="false" IsEppRequired="false" IsDisableModContact="false" IsDisableWGAllot="false" IsIncludeInExtendedSearchOnly="false" SequenceNumber="18" Type="CCTLD" IsSupportsIDN="false" Category="A">UK based domain</Tld>
    </Tlds>
  </CommandResponse>
  <Server>IMWS-A06</Server>
  <GMTTimeDifference>+5:30</GMTTimeDifference>
  <ExecutionTime>0.047</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>
```

I make the call like so:

```php
$response = Http::get(env('NAMECHEAP_SANDBOX'), [
    'ApiUser' => env('NAMECHEAP_APIUSER'),
    'ApiKey' => env('NAMECHEAP_APIKEY'),
    'UserName' => env('NAMECHEAP_USERNAME'),
    'Command' => 'namecheap.domains.gettldlist',
    'ClientIp' => env('NAMECHEAP_IP')
]);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody(), 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

I get a response where gTLDs are shown like so:
[tld-list-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuabD.png)

The overall structure of the returned array is:

[structure-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZnhL.png)

However, I would like to retrieve a list of names that are simple as shown in their API docs. Like biz, cc, and so on. If anyone could point me in a direction it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is misleading. The whole data contained in the SimpleXMLElement is not showing.

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody(), 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

/* I don't think this is needed
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
*/

dd($xml) // This should look like your images. Notice no extra data is in the Tlds.

dd($xml->CommandResponse->Tlds->Tld[0]); // surprise, the data is there.
```

If you want to dump the attributes, you can use string casting to do it.

```php
foreach ($xml->CommandResponse->Tlds->Tld as $tld) {
    dump( (string) $tld['Name'] );
}
```

For example, this is the output of trying this out with the sample XML
[image]

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a way you can get to the attributes themselves if you want.

Comment: Also, as to why the data wasn't showing, this is in the php documentation: *"Note: SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most methods. They cannot be viewed using var_dump() or anything else which can examine objects."*

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked well on your first edit as well.

Comment: As a tip, you don't actually need that `LIBXML_NOCDATA` option, which is only really relevant when turning the object _back into XML_. The only reason people _think_ they need it is, again, because of things not showing up in `var_dump` and friends.